# Is it possible to move free space from Ubuntu partition to Windows, when Windows is located before Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have Windows partition `sda2` and then, next to it, extended partition with Ubuntu `sda6`. Can I reallocate some of Ubuntu's free space to `sda2`? I know I can boot from liveCD GParted and cut some GB from `sda6`, but then the unallocated space will be after `sda6` and not before, am I right?

Is it possible to add the unallocated space to `sda2` or merge it, if not possible due to partitions position? From the screenshot, it looks like that space can be stuck in the middle of the extended partition:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah GParted should be able to handle that. You'll obviously need to do that from an offline state though (By that I mean from a LiveCD/USB session).

1. Shrink sda6 (ext4).
2. Move sda6 (ext4) right.
3. Shrink sd4 (extended).
4. Grow sda2 (ntfs).

Gparted should work out most of that for you but that's what I'd expect it to do. Only the move operations will take any significant time.

Oh and you'll need to make sure you've shut Windows down properly or it won't be able to edit the NTFS partition.

It's possible (though a small possibility in this case) that moving the disk partitions will alter their sdax assignment. This shouldn't be an issue these days (with grub and fstab using uuids) but you should be aware that this can be a problem. It's easily fixable from a LiveCD so don't panic if doing this stops Ubuntu from booting.

Comment: Moving the start of `/dev/sda6` will also break GRUB which will need to be reinstalled while booted from a LiveCD/USB. The easiest way to do that is using BootRepair program

Comment: @Sergey Doesn't that depend on where grub is installed? If it's installed in the MBR (as I thought it is in most dual-boot setups), it shouldn't be affected.

Comment: I wanted to expand sda2 eventually, not sda6. Sorry if I didn't made this clear, English is not my native language.

Comment: @MelodyNelson Completely my fault but similar applies. I'll just rewrite to account for that.

Comment: @Oli: It seems that GRUB's Stage 1 can load Stage 2 only by sector number. Stage2 in this case is located on `/dev/sda6`, so moving the start of the partition will break the bootloader. There also may be Stage 1.5 which, if installed, can load Stage 2 using normal filesystem access. Whether Stage 1.5 was installed depends on the presence of free space after MBR. http://gparted.sourceforge.net/faq.php#faq-13 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB#GRUB_version_2

Comment: Either way, while it might be scary , it's *quite* simple to fix: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System